# retain a window as modal

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, modal-dialog

**Background**

I'm working on a windows application using wpf, which is work flow automation. so users flows from form-to-form and back..

hence i've decided implement forms as page and use a frame on my main window into which i'm loading the forms (read pages) so it's basically

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new object); //forward
```

or

```
NavigationService.GoBack(); // going back
```

What i'd not forseen when choosing the approach was that I needed modal windows in the flow, which acts as launching board for specific paths.

I've managed to achieve the task by calling up the "jumping board" windows as modal and hiding them when navigating forward. When i'm calling these "jumping board"'s i'm hooking up as follows:

```
NavigationService.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(CameBack);
jumpingBoard.ShowDialogue();
```

and in Cameback:

```
CameBack()
{
  jumpingBoard.Visiblity = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

In the jumpingBoard, I do a `this.Hide()` on navigating forward.

This is because, the user may have to use multiple path's on this board before the total process is completed.

**My Problem**

it's that once I'm back on the jumpingBoard via CameBack, the jumpingBoard is no longer modal. I can trigger actions on under lying form through mouse and keyboard even while the jumpingBoard is the top most window.

I've worked around this by doing a `owner.IsEnabled = false` in the `jumpingBoard_Activated` and `owner.IsEnabled = true` in `jumpingBoard_Closed`

so any recommendations or suggestions?